# What does c represent in Sipser's explanation of the modified post correspondence problem Introduction to the Theory of Computation book?

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata

I'm supposed to perform actions corresponding to the different steps in Sipser's explanation of the Modified Post Correspondence Problem, but I'm not sure I understand the third step.
The part I'm referring to is:

Part 3. For every $a, b, c ∈ Γ$ and every $q, r ∈ Q$ where $q$ != $q_{reject}$,

if δ(q, a) = (r, b,L), put $\frac{cqa}{rcb}$ into P'.

What does c represent? Any other value besides a, b in Γ? So if I'm constructing a domino for every value that exists outside of that one?

Comment: Not everyone owns a copy of the Theory of Computation. Answering while knowing only a small part of the explanation and notations could be difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domino simulates a move to the left. Initially the head of the TM is reading $a$. It will rewrite that cell into $b$. Note that $a,b\in\Gamma$ are fixed by the specific transition $\delta(q,a) = (r,b,L)$. Then the head moves left. We do not know the symbol on that new position, so we allow any $c\in \Gamma$ for that domino.